# How to make transparent background in Pyqtgraph?

Tags: colors, background, transparent, pyqtgraph

I'm currently creating graphs using pyqtgraph, however I'm stuck with the background color since I would like it to be transparent or basically to have no background at all. I've read the docs but so far I haven't been able to achieve this. I'm currently using the following method to have a white background, but the parameter 'None' is not accepted:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

pg.setConfigOption('background', (255,255,255))
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alpha channel controls transparency. Try something like

```
pg.setConfigOption('background', (255,255,255, 100))
```

Adjust the last value as desired. Alpha value of zero results in a fully transparent color; value of 255 results in a fully opaque color.

See docs [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#color-pen-and-brush-functions).

Comment: Hi @Basil, I've tried adjusting the value to 0 in the alpha channel as you suggested, but it still looks completely white. You can visualize the result here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noIjc.jpg I don't know if it's actually doing something with the value given to the alpha parameter.

Comment: It works for me. Can you update your question with a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Of course @Basil, I appreciate your help in advance, I've created a sample GUI with Qt Designer (containing only the graph I showed you) and the sample python code so it is simple for you to recreate (that creates the graph of the previous photo). I saved both documents in this Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X9Hlq_DCzMkB-savfDsDNHUvTalkgU7a?usp=sharing. You only need to write the location of the Sample.ui file in the python script. Let me know if you need anything else. As soon as you run the code you should see the graph from the previous image.

Comment: In your case the `.ui` file contains the stylesheet that controls the opacity of your `widget` and `widget_2` elements.  It ultimately overrides your config options. I believe you want to adjust the 55% in the property `background-color` of `widget_2` to get the result you want. To do that, in Qt Designer select `widget_2` and edit its `styleSheet` property.

Comment: It's true @Basil, the Qt Designer is overriding what I wrote on the Python file. Thank you for the help you gave me, have a Happy New Year!!